# document.getElementById

Tags: javascript

I'm working on an assignment in my beginner Javascript class that involves an element document.getElementById on the first line below the var total. There is an error of missing ";" but the semicolon is there. So I know that it must be something else. Here is the code. Any suggestions?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Price Calculator</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fixOrder(){
const TAX = 0.975;
var numPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cost").value);


var subtotal = numPrice * TAX;
var total = subtotal + tax;
document.getElementById("cost").value = "$" cost.ToFixed(2);
document.getElementById("tax").value ="$" tax.ToFixed(2);
document.getElementById("total").value ="$" total.ToFixed(2);
}

function placeOrder(){
if (document.getElementById("cost") == ""
isNaN(document.getElementById("cost")
alert("Sorry,you must enter a numeric value to place order")
if (document.getElementById("tax") == ""
isNaN(document.getElementById("tax")
alert("Sorry, you must enter a numeric value to place the order");
}
</script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#00f3F1">
<frame align="left">
<legend>
<h1 align="center">Price Calculator</h1>
</legend>
<form name="purchases" action="donut.php"  method="POST">

Price:<p> <input type="text" id="cost" name="cost" value="" onchange="fixOrder">
</p>
Tax:<p>  <input type="text" id="tax" name="tax" value="" onchange="fixOrder">
</p>
Total:<p> <input type="text" id="total" name="total" value="" >
</p>
</form>
</frame>



<div id="cost" name="cost" value="" onchange="placeOrder();"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [validate, validate, validate](http://validator.w3.org) (It won't actually fix *this* issue, but you have lots of problems with the markup). Also, you need to learn about [label](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1).

Comment: @Quentin I haven't used it in a while but I'm pretty sure the HTML validator doesn't check JS syntax.  [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) however will check your syntax and coding style.  Some people don't like the strict style it tries to enforce but I've found it's a good idea to adopt most of its suggestions.  It's author, Douglas Crockford explains the reasoning behind most of it's rules in his excellent book __JavaScript: The Good Parts__. If JSlint is too strict for you, you could also try its more forgiving cousin [JShint](http://www.jshint.com/).

Comment: @UselessCode - `parseFloat` does not have a `radix` argument. You're right about `parseInt` though.

Comment: Guys, the guy said he was a beginner. There's no need to downvote him. It might be terrible code too, but we all started somewhere and none of us were born being able to write good code with good syntax. We slowly learned how to do it.

Comment: @JamesAllardice Oops. Could have sworn it did must of been thinking of something else.  I guess it's because I hardly ever had a need for `pasreFloat` in any real-world projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has already been pointed out by the numerous other answers, there are a multitude of problems with your code. This answer is intended to address all of the mistakes and shortcomings.

I'll go from the top of the posted code. Firstly, you may have simply not pasted it into the question, but you're missing a `DOCTYPE` declaration at the top of the file. All HTML documents should begin with a `DOCTYPE`, for example:

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

Into the JavaScript, the `const` keyword, while valid, is not supported by a lot of older browsers and is definitely best avoided. Replace it with `var`, it will make no difference.

To concatenate strings in JavaScript you use the `+` operator:

`document.getElementById("cost").value = "$" + cost.toFixed(2);`

Also notice that I've changed `ToFixed` to `toFixed`. Another problem with the above line is the variable `cost`, which you've not defined. You may have meant `numPrice`, but I'm not entirely sure!

On the next line, you're using `tax` instead of `TAX`. Variable names in JavaScript are case-sensitive, so `tax` is also undefined.

Your `if` statement conditions are wrong. I'm assuming you meant this:

```
if(document.getElementById("cost").value == "" || isNaN(document.getElementById("cost").value)
```

There's a few changes to that line. Firstly, you were comparing a DOM element itself (`getElementById` returns a DOM element), rather than the value of it. Secondly, you were missing the closing parentheses, and finally, you needed some operator between the two conditions. I think you were after the "or" operator, `||`. There's a similar issue with your second `if` statement.

You're missing a semi-colon off the end of your first `alert` line. While that's still valid, it's definitely good practice to always include the semi-colon.

Back into the HTML, you're trying to call the `fixOrder` JS function, but you've missed the parentheses:

```
<input type="text" id="cost" name="cost" value="" onchange="fixOrder()">
```

To be really picky, you shouldn't really use inline event handlers, but I won't go into that here.

I'm not sure why you're using a `frame` element the way you are, but I have a feeling it would be better replaced by a `div`, or simply nothing at all (again, I may not have the full picture if you haven't posted the full code).

On your `body` tag you're using the `bgcolor` attribute. That should definitely be replaced by CSS. You can use the `background-color` property.

Comment: I didn't use the doctype because it wasn't used in the book examples. But I will from now on. I don't know what you mean by the inline event handlers,but I'll be looking it up. We use event handlers in my Visual Basic class, but it's build in. This is only my 3rd coding experience. I'll get better as long as I practice and have great teachers like you guys. Thank you.

Comment: By inline event handlers I mean things like the `onclick` attribute on HTML elements. As you said, just look it up :) Sorry if my answer seemed at all condescending, it wasn't meant to. Of course you will get better with practice! Glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a concatenation operator here (notice the `+`):

```
document.getElementById("cost").value = "$" + cost.ToFixed(2);
```

You also have syntax errors in your `if` statement. They should be:

```
if (document.getElementById("cost") == "" || isNaN(document.getElementById("cost")) {
   ...
}
```

and

```
if (document.getElementById("tax") == "" || isNaN(document.getElementById("tax")) {
   ...
}
```

Also, please consider indenting your code. It makes it much easier to read and maintain and will help you spot your syntax errors much more easily as well.

There are a few other errors (not syntax), but I will let you figure those out; this is homework after all.

**EDIT**: It looks like you're a real beginner, so in addition to what you're learning in class, I'd pick up some books that are tailored for beginners. [Here are some that I was able to find](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2010/03/top-10-best-javascript-books-that-beginners-should-read.html).

Comment: @minitech my mistake. I've fixed it. I was under the impression that `const` was wrong.

Comment: Same here, but then I tested it. +1

Comment: @minitech I don't see it that often, which is why I assumed that it was wrong :p That'll teach me!

Comment: @VivinPaliath - While the `const` keyword is correct, I don't believe it's supported in IE below version 9. I would definitely stay away from it for the foreseeable future!

Comment: [`const is a Mozilla-specific extension and is not part of ECMAScript 5. 

It is supported in Firefox & Chrome (V8) and partially supported in Opera 9+ & Safari (though it acts as a var). It is not supported in IE6-9.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

Comment: @JamesAllardice and Useless Code, thanks for the information!

Comment: I'm so grateful for forums like this. It's a life saver. This is an online course I'm taking, so beside the threaded discussion with other students, this is help in the true sense of the word. As I gain knowledge and experience I will certainly try to pass it on as it has been given to me. I can't comment to much on the code because I still new in learning the language and syntax.

Answer (score 2):

In javascript, you concatenate strings with the `+` operator. Instead of

```
document.getElementById("cost").value = "$" cost.ToFixed(2);
```

Use

```
document.getElementById("cost").value = "$" + cost.ToFixed(2);
```

---

Your if statements are also wrong. Instead of

```
if (document.getElementById("cost") == ""
isNaN(document.getElementById("cost")
alert("Sorry,you must enter a numeric value to place order")
```

Use

```
if(isNaN(document.getElementById("cost").value))
    alert("Sorry,you must enter a numeric value to place order");
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `+` between `"$"` and the `xxx.ToFixed(2)`s. What's more, it's `toFixed`, not `ToFixed`. You're also missing closing parenthesis everywhere (`if` statements and `isNaN` calls) as well as a `||` between the two.

Answer (score 1):

A few things here:

1. you should optimize the code by setting variables for your `document.getElementById("cost")`.  So `var c = document.getElementById("cost");`
2. your `if statements` are missing closing parentheses and `or` operators.

   if (document.getElementById("cost") == ""
   isNaN(document.getElementById("cost")

should be

```
if (document.getElementById("cost") == "" || 
isNaN(document.getElementById("cost"))
```

You are also missing a `;` after your alert here

```
if (document.getElementById("cost") == ""
isNaN(document.getElementById("cost")
alert("Sorry,you must enter a numeric value to place order")
```

Comment: This is a new one to me, optimize my variables. Thank you. The other errors I couldn't see because this is actually my third written code.

Answer (score 0):

That code was a total mess. I've fixed it up. It should work now:

```
function fixOrder()
{
    const TAX = new Number(0.975);

    var numPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cost").value);
    var cost = new Number(document.getElementById("cost").value);
    var total = new Number(document.getElementById("total").value);

    var subtotal = numPrice * TAX;
    var total = new Number(subtotal + TAX);

    document.getElementById("cost").value = "$" + cost.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("tax").value ="$" + TAX.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("total").value ="$" + total.toFixed(2);
}

function placeOrder()
{
    if (document.getElementById("cost").value == "" || isNaN(document.getElementById("cost").value)) {
        alert("Sorry,you must enter a numeric value to place order");
    }

    if (document.getElementById("tax").value == "" || isNaN(document.getElementById("tax").value)) {
        alert("Sorry, you must enter a numeric value to place the order");
    }
}
```

Comment: Never, ever, *ever* use `new Number`. Use `parseFloat` instead, or `Number` if you absolutely must for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of errors going on here, first, you need to concatenate the string "$" with cost.ToFixed(2); using the concatenation operator +, apply this for the next 2 lines.

Other errors are in the if conditions, you are missing the closing ) in both if conditions, also, I guess that you want to check that the value of the text box is empty so you need to add .value.

here is the working source

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Price Calculator</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fixOrder(){
const TAX = 0.975;
var numPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cost").value);


var subtotal = numPrice * TAX;
var total = subtotal + tax;
document.getElementById("cost").value = "$" +cost.ToFixed(2);
document.getElementById("tax").value ="$" +tax.ToFixed(2);
document.getElementById("total").value ="$" +total.ToFixed(2);
}

function placeOrder(){
if (document.getElementById("cost").value == "" ||     isNaN(document.getElementById("cost").value))
alert("Sorry,you must enter a numeric value to place order");
if (document.getElementById("tax").value == "" ||     isNaN(document.getElementById("tax").value))
alert("Sorry, you must enter a numeric value to place the order");
}
</script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#00f3F1">
<frame align="left">
<legend>
<h1 align="center">Price Calculator</h1>
</legend>
<form name="purchases" action="donut.php"  method="POST">

Price:<p> <input type="text" id="cost" name="cost" value="" onchange="fixOrder">
</p>
Tax:<p>  <input type="text" id="tax" name="tax" value="" onchange="fixOrder">
</p>
Total:<p> <input type="text" id="total" name="total" value="" >
</p>
</form>
</frame>



<div id="cost" name="cost" value="" onchange="placeOrder();"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You saved the day. Thank you. I see there is more than one way to skin a cat. I'm seeing that variables can be used in a variety ways. I guess that's why they're called variables. I gonna have to get creative like you. I feel I'm getting something here that's truly awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>if ($(this).attr('name') == 'time') {
    var value = $(this).val();
    parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
    alert(value);
    editEntry.time = value;
}
</p>
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.